# Fatal error: Class 'Redis' not found

Tags: php, redis

На сервере был установлен PHP 5.3 и к нему PHPRedis, на страницах обычный код `<?php
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);`
Все нормально работало. По техническим нуждам пришлось перейти на 5.5, но при загрузке страницы теперь выдает:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Redis' not found
```

Причем версия PHP в консоли осталась 5.3, а страницы открывает через 5.5. Соответственно команда в самой консоли: `php -r "if (new Redis() == true){ echo \"\r\n OK \r\n\"; }"` ошибку не выдает. Что можно сделать, заново переустанавливать phpredis или можно что-то прописать?

Answer (score 1):

Выполните composer dump-autoload.
Попробуйте вместо `$redis = new Redis()` использовать `$redis = new \Redis();`
И убедитесь что подключен `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Все просто напишите одну строчку - чтобы подключить этот класс

```
unclude_once(__DIR__ .'/RedisClass.php');
```

только нужно понять из какого файла он вызывается и какой путь до файла с классом REDIS

возможно у вас "полетела" автозагрузка классов - переделайте ее под новые стандарты http://php.net/Autoload

Comment: еще бы найти откуда :D

Comment: ну что ж это просто. Например в Notepad ++ есть поиск в файлах Ctrl+Shift+f для этого вам необходимо скачать файлы себе на комп и запустить поиск в этих файлах например class Redis

Comment: Может чем поможет, в коносоли теперь выдает при вызове phpredis: `PHP Warning:  Module 'redis' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: документ нашел, `include_once('/tmp/phpredis/redis.c');`
Но теперь просто весь текст документа выводит на экран

Comment: прошу извинить, но формат файла .с - Исходный код C/C++ я специализируюсь на файлах .php

Comment: могу предположить лишь одно - если это единственный документ с этим классом, то каким то образом этот класс считывался через какой-то конвектор файлов. Если так, то в этом случае вам необходима библиотека с php файлом класса REDIS. Редиска прям какая то :)